# How to make a time slider like Manipulate[n,{n,1,20,1}]?

Tags: manipulate, slider

I want to make a time slider varied from **12:00:00 Jan 1,2015** to **22:30:00 Jan 1,2015** for every 5 minute.

So like using `Manipulate[n,{n,1,20,1}]`,

```
Manipulate[tt,{tt,{2015,1,1,12,0,0.},{2015,1,1,22,30,0.},{0,0,0,0,5,0.}}]
```

but it doesn't work! Any idea?

Comment: This may give a quick hint  `Manipulate[
 DateObject[date], {date, 
  DateRange[{2015, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0.}, {2015, 1, 1, 22, 30, 0.}, 
   Quantity[5, "Minutes"]]}]`  You can of course pull most of the code into the manipulate function rather than in the manipulate range specification for date.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be as simple as this:

```
Manipulate[
 DateString[t], {t, DateObject[{2015, 1, 1, 12, 0}], 
  DateObject[{2015, 1, 1, 22, 30}], Quantity[5, "Minutes"]}]
```

Using DateObjects rather than a List to indicate a date & time seems to work.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this right now but I think this will work.

```
basetime = AbsoluteTime[{2015,1,1,12,0,0}];
max = AbsoluteTime[{2015,1,1,22,30,0}];
Manipulate[
  DateList[basetime + millis],
{millis, 0, max, 300000}]
```

Comment: There's at least one typo in there.

Comment: Is there? I can't see any but I'm also from mobile right now